# Access email from a particular folder in Outlook, within a specific date range (user Input) using "exchangelib" in Python

Tags: python, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

Summary of the requirement :
To access emails from a specific folder in Outlook within a user given date range,

> ex: all mails from June or all mails from 23-June-2020 to 15-July-2020

So far we have tried the following but the issues are :

1. Date range is not giving correct output
2. It is taking too long to give output, also sometimes returning with a timeout error.

The Code:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, DELEGATE, Configuration, IMPERSONATION, FaultTolerance,EWSDateTime,EWSTimeZone,Message
import datetime 
import pandas as pd


new_password = "your password"

credentials = Credentials(username = 'username', password = new_password)
config = Configuration(server ='outlook.office365.com', credentials = credentials)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address ='username', credentials = credentials, autodiscover = False, config = config, access_type = DELEGATE)

#first approach.....................................

conversation_id = []
datetime_received = []
has_attachment = []
Senders = []

for i in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:40]:
    if isinstance(i, Message):
        if i.datetime_received:
            if ((i.datetime_received).year == 2020):
                if ((i.datetime_received).month == 7):
                        if i.conversation_id:
                            print("conversation id: ", i.conversation_id.id)
                            conversation_id.append(i.conversation_id.id)
                        if not i.conversation_id:
                            conversation_id.append("Not available")

                        if i.sender:
                            print("Sender name : ", i.sender.name)
                            Senders.append(i.sender.name)
                        if not i.sender:
                            Senders.append("not available")

                        if i.datetime_received:
                            print("Time : ", i.datetime_received.date)
                            datetime_received.append(i.datetime_received.date)
                        if not i.datetime_received:
                            datetime_received.append("not available")

                        if i.has_attachments:
                            print("Has attachment: ", i.has_attachments)
                            has_attachment.append(i.has_attachments)
                        if not i.has_attachments:
                            has_attachment.append("not available")
                    
                    

# second approach.....................................................................
items_for_2019 = account.inbox.filter(start__range=(
    tz.localize(EWSDateTime(2019, 8, 1)),
    tz.localize(EWSDateTime(2020, 1, 1))
)) 

for i in items_for_2019:
    print("")



#third approach.........................................................................

for item in account.inbox.filter(datetime_received__range=(tz.localize(EWSDateTime(2019, 8, 1)),tz.localize(EWSDateTime(2020, 1, 1)))):
    print(item.sender.name)
```

> first approach is working for specific month but extremely slow

> second and third approach giving wrong output

A little guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start` field belongs to `CalendarItem`. It is not a valid field for `Message` objects. That's why your 2nd approach does not work.

Your 3rd approach should work. Which output do you see, and what did you expect?

If your queries are taking a long time, try to limit the fields you are fetching for each item, by using the `.only()` QuerySet method.

Comment: Hey @Erik, thanks for replying. The 3rd approach was giving wrong data, as in, the data in the output was out of range from what we had given.

Comment: And as U can see from the code above, I was printing only one field i.e sender.name but after running for a long time and fetching only 3 to 4 records, the code would throw a "Server Timeout Error". Just for reference the mailboxes I want to access have thousands of mails, out of which I want atleast 6 months of mails.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the 3rd approach returns items with a datetime_received outside the range. This is a well-tested code path. If you are getting timeouts, try using .only() and configure a retry policy if you are still seeing timeouts.

Comment: Hi @Eric, will check the code with ".only()"  and get back to U.

Comment: Hi @Eric, I checked the code, it is working fine. Thank You so much, for the replies and the Library.